# Can not build thisJoinPoint lazily for this advice since it has no suitable guard

Tags: aop, aspectj

What is a "suitable guard" and what does it look like?

[Linked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930098/spring-aop-error-can-not-build-thisjoinpoint-lazily-for-this-advice) because it refers to the same compiler message and the answer mentions a guard but not how to create one. Looked through the AspectJ docs but did not find and answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Lint warning is usually switched off in AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) within Eclipse, but you can activate it as a warning or even error like this (I had to do it to actually see it at all when trying to reproduce your issue):

[image: AspectJ compiler setting for "no guard for lazy tjp"]

You can just ignore the Lint warning because basically it only says that there is no way for certain pointcuts to populate the `thisJoinPoint` object lazily during runtime because the pointcut has no dynamic component like `if()`, `cflow()` or similar, which is actually good news because it means that all your joinpoints can be determined statically during compile/weave time and are thus faster than dynamic pointcuts. On the other hand, the warning says that the tjp object always has to be created because for some reason it is also always needed during runtime and thus cannot be instantiated lazily.

Comment: I am researching interaction of aspects, which is why I turned it on. Normally, I think of lazy (or delayed) evaluation as a good thing - in this case it's the opposite. Thanks for the succinct explanation.